# How can I limit output to the terminal width

Tags: bash, shell

When I use `pstree` I see that lines only go up to the terminal width (that is, no word wrap), but when I `grep` the output, it does wrap. What function is it using to change this behavior?

```
bash$ pstree
\--= 76211 _spotlight /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker MDSImporte
bash$ pstree | grep MDSImporte
\--= 76211 _spotlight /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mdworker MDSImporterWorker com.apple.Spotlight.ImporterWorker.89
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`pstree` seems to think that you don't want wrapped output, thus it asks the terminal about its width and outputs just as much. `top` and `ps` behave similar.

You can avoid this by piping the output through `cat`:

```
pstree | cat
```

---

Edit: Ah, I see that you want not avoid it, but add the chopping.

An easy way is piping the output of your command through `less -S` (or `less --chop-long-lines`, more verbosely). (You may want to combine this with some other options, see the manual page, depending on your preferences).

```
pstree | grep MDSImporte | less -SEX
```

will show your the lines cut off at terminal size.

Comment: That.. um.. huh.  `R` will preserve coloration as well (such as from `git --color`), the possible option acronym is almost appropriate: `less -SEXIER` (the second `E` apparently ignored)

Comment: Plus one for `less -SEX`... oh wait

Comment: `less -S` does the trick but `less -SEX` seem easier to remember !

Comment: `less -S` stops until you press `q` or `CTRL+C` so `less -SEX` works much better for scripting.

Answer (score 5):

`pstree` must be checking to see if it's writing to a terminal, and if so it queries the terminal for its column width and then limits the output accordingly. You could do something similar:

```
WIDTH=`stty size | cut -d ' ' -f 2`            # Get terminal's character width
pstree | grep MDSImporte | cut -c 1-${WIDTH}   # Chop output after WIDTH chars
```

Other utilities (e.g. `less`) can do this for you but may have other side-effects (e.g. prompting you to press the space bar after each page of output).

Also...

If you're asking how you could determine whether a script is writing to a terminal, file, or pipe, you could do this:

```
[ -t 1 ] && WIDTH=`stty size | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
pstree | grep MDSImporte | cut -c 1-${WIDTH}
```

This will set `WIDTH` if and only if standard output is a terminal. If it is, it'll limit the output to `WIDTH` characters (by invoking `cut -c 1-80`, say). If it's not, it won't limit the output (because `cut -c 1-` does nothing).

Comment: to get the terminal width you can just use the variable $COLUMNS

Answer (score 1):

it checks whether the output is a terminal.

other programs do similar things:

```
grep --color=auto
ls --color=auto
```